# Extract the order list from an ordered correlation matrix: R

Tags: r, r-corrplot

I created a correlation matrix and visualize it using the `corrplot` function with the following code

```
temp<-matrix(rexp(25, rate=.1), ncol=5)
tempCor<-cor(temp)
tempCor <- data.frame(tempCor)
names(tempCor) <- c(1:5)
corrplot(t(tempCor),method="pie",order="AOE")
```

Here is the result of the `corrplot` funciton

[image: plot]

Is there any way to get the order list from this result, which is `(4,5,1,3,2)`?

Comment: There is a function for this `corrMatOrder`; so use `corrMatOrder(t(tempCor), order="AOE")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(corrplot)
set.seed(1234)
temp <- matrix(rexp(25, rate=.1), ncol=5)
tempCor <- cor(temp)
tempCor <- data.frame(tempCor)
names(tempCor) <- c(1:5)
out <- corrplot(t(tempCor),method="pie",order="AOE")
dimnames(out)
```

Here is what you are looking for:

```
[[1]]
[1] "5" "1" "3" "4" "2"

[[2]]
[1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5"
```